# pass data from deleted table to another

Tags: mysql, database-design

This is the situation:

I have a table, with name `TABLE_1` I would like delete TABLE_1 and then create another table with the same name and some of its columns.

`TABLE_1` has records, but I need to pass it to the new table `TABLE_1`

What is the the most effective way to to this?

**UPDATE**

```
old TABLE_1:
    ID int(11) NOT NULL
    ACTIVE int(11) NOT NULL
    SENT_DATE DATETIME
    SENT INT(11) NOT NULL
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50)


new TABLE_1:
    ID_TABLE_1 int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    STATUS TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)
    SENT_DATE DATETIME
    SENT TINYINT(1) DEFAULT(0)
```

In the `ACTIVE` and `SENT` columns are stores just 1 or 0. The relation between columns are (from old to new):

```
* ID -> ID_TABLE_1
* ACTIVE -> STATUS
* SENT_DATE -> SENT_DATE
* SENT -> SENT
```

Comment: Please show us what `TABLE_1` looks like now, and what columns you want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the existing rows and don't want the table renamed but only a few columns altered/changed/dropped, you can do this with a single `ALTER TABLE` statement. This will only fail if there is no index on `(id)`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_1
   CHANGE COLUMN id 
      id_table_1 int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-- ADD PRIMARY KEY 
--    (id_table_1),
   CHANGE COLUMN active 
      status TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
   CHANGE COLUMN sent
      sent TINYINT DEFAULT 0,
   DROP COLUMN description ;
```

Tested at [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/283d8)

Comment: why it fails if there is not an index on `ID`?

Comment: Because columns with `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute need to be indexed. You can uncomment the 2 lines about the primary key and the primary key constraint and an index will be added. Then it will not fail.

Comment: Good, the pk and index already exists.
What about auto_increment? `ID` in the original `TABLE_1` is not auto_increment